# Moment Timezone has no data for EDT in react

Tags: react-native, momentjs

React native project has

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022'
...
    var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
    jun.tz('EDT')
```

Results in error about absence of EDT

> Moment Timezone has no data for EDT. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/

`tz` object has packed zones and `America/New_York|EST EDT|50 40|01010101010101010101010|1GI70 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0|21e6` in particular

```
jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles')
```

or

```
jun.tz('UTC')
```

works as expected.

Adding time zone as suggested on the momentjs.com website doesn't change the outcome.

npm 5.0.0, node 8.0.0, moment-timezone: 0.5.14, react-moment: 0.7.0, moment: 2.22.0

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. I'm loading in moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022 which includes packed zone for America/New_York just as you've specified in your question. Still EST is valid but EDT is not

Comment: Still an issue for me. I have an if that checks for EDT and changes it to EST but that is a horrible hack.